# How to connect Angular application with more than 1 server?

Tags: angular, microservices

I have more than 1 server running on different ports.

1. `http://localhost:8081`
2. `http://localhost:8082`
3. `http://localhost:8083`

Currently, I can connect all modules/library of my Angular 2 application to any single server.

However, how to connect different library with different servers?

I am following micro-service approach for Angular application following [this](https://antoniogoncalves.org/2018/08/13/angular-libraries-and-microservices/) article,

Comment: What server(s) are you running (your own) or hitting (3rd-party)? Typically your Angular API clients (confusingly called "services" in Angular parlance) may each be configured to hit different APIs; there is nothing preventing you from doing that. Sounds like you may also want a load-balancer or reverse proxy if you wish to provide a single endpoint for your own servers, but it's unclear from your question. See also https://serverfault.com/questions/127021/what-is-the-difference-between-load-balancer-and-reverse-proxy

Comment: Micro-services has nothing to do with Angular.

Comment: @cgTag, Thanks! I meant different library of angular app would connect with different micro-services.

Comment: @WillCain, yes, my own server. Currently, I'm using a proxy.conf.json file to configure this.

Comment: Anything that you do that works for you would be the right answer. There are no rules for this. Keeping it simple for now would seem like good advice.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to take use of environment variables that you inject into your [services](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services) (assuming you have one for each service lib) each one with a specific variable and once done you can run the cli with(depending what version of the cli you running):

> ng build --env

or

> ng build --prod --env=prod

with minified production code.

and in your env files:

environment.ts:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  libOneUrl: 'http://localhost:8081',
  libTwoUrl: 'http://localhost:8082',
  libThreeUrl: 'http://localhost:8083',
};
```

and in your service.ts inject it by:

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

apiUrl = environment.libOneUrl;
```

for dev resp. prod build do same in the files environment.dev.ts resp. environment.prod.ts (set production variable to true for prod build).

Answer (score 2):

Currently, we are using the micro-frontend approach to connect with different services.
https://micro-frontends.org/